# Copy Column Data - Azure Table Storage

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

So Azure Table Storage has three default member properties for its [TableServiceEntity class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storageclient.tableserviceentity_members.aspx), one of which is Timestamp.  After release to Production, we now realize we need a CreatedDateTime property instead of Timestamp b/c we have no control over the Timestamp value, which acts more like a "Last Modified" value rather than "Created Date" value.

How can I copy the value in Timestamp currently over to my new property?  In SQL, this seems pretty straightforward, but the cloud is a different animal.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Table Storage you have no schema.  In a single "table" you can have 10 rows with a C# defined class of Person and 10 rows of class Dog with COMPLETELY different properties.

The reason I am saying this is because there is no schema, so the easiest thing to do would be to "re-insert" the rows as a batch with the new column/property added to the class.  You can also do an UPSERT as well:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2011/09/15/windows-azure-tables-introducing-upsert-and-query-projection.aspx

If the column is already defined then its easy and u would just do an update, but it sounds like that new column does not exist on the previous rows entered.

Comment: Upsert!  I think this documentation spells it out pretty well.  Thank you.

Comment: To help someone else, if you decide to use BatchMode when saving, then just be sure that you're saving back to the same PartitionKey in Azure Table Storage or you'll get an exception.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a class, just add the new field for the create date time.  Pull all the data down and copy the timestamp to the new field and then call update on the row.  If you are already doing inserts and deletes and thigns, should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: This is the process I had in mind too for coding it, but I was looking for confirmation & concrete code examples.  You both confirmed and answered my question, so thank you.